# PyYAML dumps Python dictionary with tags

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I don't understand why yaml.dump adds tags and weird informations into result:

Source file.yml content is :

```
ssh_keys:
  user1:
    - key: key1
      state: state1
```

I want to add to the file the following key :

```
key_to_add = {
  'key': key2,
  'state': state2
}
```

Here is my code :

```
import yaml 

with open('file.yml', 'r') as file:
  data = yaml.load(file)
 
print(key_to_add)
data['ssh_keys']['user1'].append(key_to_add)
print(data)
print(type(data))
print(yaml.dump(data))
```

The unexpected result:

```
{'key': 'key2', 'state': 'state2'}
{'ssh_keys': {'user1': [{'key': 'key1', 'state': 'state1'}, {'key': 'key2', 'state': 'state2'}]}}
<class 'dict'>
ssh_keys:
  user1:
    - key: 'key1'
      state: 'state1'
    - key: !!python/object/new:ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode
        args:
        - key2
        state:
          _column_number: 26
          _data_source: /home/...........
          _line_number: 34  
      state: !!python/object/new:ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode
        args:
        - state2
        state:
          _column_number: 24
          _data_source: /home/...........
          _line_number: 35
```

I was expecting the following result:

```
ssh_keys:
  user1:
    - key: 'key1'
      state: 'state1'
    - key: 'key2'
      state: 'state2'
```

Comment: PyYAML's `dump` expects a stream as second parameter. If you leave out that parameter, the output is streamed to a buffer, then the buffer is returned as a string. Doing `print(yaml.dump(data))` instead of `yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)` is inefficient with regards to time **and** space. The officially recommended extension for files containing YAML documents has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006 (YML is an older and entirely different format than YAML).

Comment: Yes I knew about it you are right. Because in my case printing was just for debug I was lazy using sys.stdout. What do you mean that YML is different then YAML ? I thought it was just because older windows restricted the extension to 3 letters only.

Comment: [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) is an XML derivative. IIRC version 1 of that pre-dates YAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a brief look at [pyyaml docs](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) and figured out below code generates desired output

```
import yaml
try:
    from yaml import CLoader as Loader, CDumper as Dumper
except ImportError:
    from yaml import Loader, Dumper

with open('file.yml', 'r') as file:
    data = yaml.load(file, Loader=Loader)

key_to_add = {
    'key': 15,
    'state': 166
}
print(key_to_add)
data['ssh_keys']['user1'].append(key_to_add)
print(data)
print(type(data))
print(yaml.dump(data, Dumper=Dumper))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping but unfortunetly, modifying my code as above doesn't change anything to the result.

Comment: is the data you trying to add string or variable ?
I believe your variable contains extra data

Comment: Ok I found out! You were so right, I thought `key2`and `state2` were strings but it was objects! I just had to str() my vars and everything works perfectly fine now! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The unexpected tags and information in the output are caused by the use of `yaml.load()` function in your code. This function is not safe and can result in the creation of unexpected Python objects when loading the YAML content, as seen in your output. To avoid this issue, you should use the `yaml.safe_load()` function instead.

Here's the modified version of your code using `yaml.safe_load()`:

```py
import yaml

with open('file.yml', 'r') as file:
    data = yaml.safe_load(file)

key_to_add = {
    'key': 'key2',
    'state': 'state2'
}

print(key_to_add)
data['ssh_keys']['user1'].append(key_to_add)
print(data)
print(type(data))
print(yaml.dump(data))
```

This should produce the expected result:

```yaml
ssh_keys:
  user1:
    - key: 'key1'
      state: 'state1'
    - key: 'key2'
      state: 'state2'
```

In addition, to further control the formatting of the output, you can use optional parameters with the `yaml.dump()` function. One such parameter is `sort_keys`, which is set to True by default. If you want to preserve the order of keys in the output, you can set `sort_keys` to False. However, in your case, this is not necessary, as using `yaml.safe_load()` should already resolve the issue. Let me know if everything goes well.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping! I edited my question with the result when using yaml.safe_load(). Any idea?

Comment: Nope. You used "`yaml.safe_dump` instead of `yaml.dump`" not `yaml.safe_load()`. I still used `yaml.dump()` at the end.

Comment: You are right sorry! I corrected and tried with yaml.safe_load() and got exactly the same result as when I use yaml.load(). :(

Comment: Thanks for helping but finaly I found out that my problem was about type of variables. See my comment in the accepted answer.

Comment: Oh haha. I made them strings to match the previous keys but I didn't realise this was what you meant.

Comment: And you were right to do that! My fault... It proves that giving peaces of code can lead to mistakes or wrong analyse if you don't have the whole context, vars etc.

Comment: @Pozinux Haha no problem. Have a good one!

Comment: It is absolute nonsense that PyYAML's `load` will create unexpected Python objects. If there are no tags in the YAML input (as is the case in the case the OP presents), `load` and `safe_load` result in the same Python data-structure.

Comment: `yaml.safe_load(file)` is basically `yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)` which I've found to always gave me my expected results, unlike the normal `Loader`. So when I read OP's question about "adding tags and weird information into result", I instantly thought that would be the issue. I defaulted to using strings (see the other comments above) when I ran it on my machine and it worked, I posted my solution.